# Manipulate items inside of mulitple arrays and objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, data-manipulation

I need to manipulate and access to the orderItem data and inside this orderItem object access MenuItem object, my purpose is to grab some data from orderItem and also from MenuItem.

**Object that returns**

```
{ Order: [ { OrderItem: [Array] } ] }
```

**Inside Order (order.Order)**

```
[
[1]   {
[1]     OrderItem: [
[1]       [Object], [Object], [Object],
[1]       [Object], [Object], [Object],
[1]       [Object], [Object], [Object],
[1]       [Object], [Object], [Object],
[1]       [Object], [Object], [Object],
[1]       [Object], [Object], [Object],
[1]       [Object], [Object], [Object],
[1]       [Object], [Object], [Object],
[1]       [Object]
[1]     ]
[1]   }
[1] ]
```

**Menu Item**

```
[
[1]   [
[1]     {
[1]       id: 86,
[1]       price: 180,
[1]       quantity: 1,
[1]       menuItemId: 1,
[1]       orderId: 1,
[1]       MenuItem: [Object]
[1]     },
[1]     {
[1]       id: 87,
[1]       price: 135,
[1]       quantity: 2,
[1]       menuItemId: 7,
[1]       orderId: 1,
[1]       MenuItem: [Object]
[1]     },
[1]     {
[1]       id: 88,
[1]       price: 170,
[1]       quantity: 2,
[1]       menuItemId: 3,
[1]       orderId: 1,
[1]       MenuItem: [Object]
[1]     },
[1]     {
[1]       id: 89,
[1]       price: 170,
[1]       quantity: 3,
[1]       menuItemId: 3,
[1]       orderId: 1,
[1]       MenuItem: [Object]
[1]     },
etc
etc
etc
```

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: You would need to traverse the array through forEach or map methods and convert it into desirable end response. If you can share the end output object we could write a function to achieve that.